how to send audio data to microphone?
from pygame._sdl2.audio import get_audio_device_names
from pygame import mixer
import pygame
import keyboard
import time
pygame.mixer.init()
def list_devices():
    return get_audio_device_names(True)
def play(device, mp3file):
    mixer.init(devicename = device)
    mixer.music.load(mp3file)
    mixer.music.play()
    print(f"Playing: {mp3file} to {device}")
    while mixer.music.get_busy() and keyboard.is_pressed('escape') == False:
        time.sleep(0.1)

def soundboard(device):
    while not keyboard.is_pressed("escape"):
        if keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl+s"):
            play(device, "test2.mp3")
        time.sleep(0.1)

if __name__=="__main__":
    for dev in list_devices():
        print(dev)
    soundboard("CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)")

I've tried pygame based on a SO answer i found but it doesn't work. I've tried setting it to the mic i need it on but it doesn't move in properties.

by move i meant the sound bar thingy that moves when it gets audio

I think your title needs cleaning up, you don't send audio to a microphone you receive audio from it.
